# Script from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/platform.png” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“image/png”)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mime, liveserver

Apologies if this is a repetitive question however I have looked all over and found no suitable solution for my particular issue.
I am attempting to build a simple JavaScript game but am having issues with importing images.

For reference, here is my relevant code:

index.html

```
<canvas id="gameScreen" width="1420" height="965"></canvas>
<script src="src/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

And from my index.js file:

`import platform from "../assets/platform.png";`

I am receiving the following error when trying to import this image:

`Script from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/platform.png” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“image/png”).`

I have tried changing the 'type' specified in the script tag, to no avail.
Also, I should note I am using the Live Server extension.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why import an image and not "reference" an image? You may have cross domain issues in play but that is hard to discern given what we have here. Suggest HTTPS over HTTP.  Info on canvas and images: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the ES6 `import` statement can't be used to import anything except JavaScript modules.

Tools like Webpack — which pre-process `import` statements to convert JS programs using ES6 modules into a format that browsers which doesn't support modules can use — can do things with non-JS resources.

They aren't executing the JavaScript, so the rules for them are different.

At the simple end of the scale, this involves copying the non-JS file to the build directory and replacing the `import` with a variable declaration and assigning a URL (in a string) to that variable.

Since you aren't using a bundler, you need to do that yourself.

Replace:

> ```
> import platform from "../assets/platform.png";
> ```

with something like

```
const platform = "/path/to/platform.png";
```